# 502.3 Bad Gateway Error While Submitting a Form using Post Method in ASP.net Core RC2

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am making a ERP with Identity Core RC 2. I am facing a very strange problem. I am putting a relationship between my User table which is "ASPNETUSER" and other table. The problem is that when I add this relationship my application starts giving 502.3 Bad Gateway Error when I post my form for insertion, but when I removed it, it starts working fine. Please look into this. I am very frustrated due to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set `options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34836837/315935) or in UPDATED part of [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34292291/315935).

Comment: Dear @Oleg! Sorry your solution isn't work

Comment: Do you use the latest `Newtonsoft.Json` too? In general it's important to understand that **any long operation** like setting of breakpoint on any line of the server code and waiting about 1 min follows to 502.3 Bad Gateway Error. It means that 502.3 Bad Gateway Error can have really many reasons.

Comment: Can it be that after the changes the application takes a long time to start and IIS timeouts? Try running your application without IIS/IISEcpress first and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584125/asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-postback-very-slow-on-first-execution) is related.

Do you expierence the memory growth as well?

Comment: Yes I do. Right now I am planing to move to other options

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me:

To use this,
https://gist.github.com/rynowak/9488b3b1a6b81876d8b14de72feb0857
 paste that class into your project, and add the following line to your ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<IModelBinderFactory, MyModelBinderFactory>();
```

Full explanation:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4666